# How to Implement Breadcrumbs for nested Categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, breadcrumbs

My categories can be nested about 6 levels deep at most. The problem I am having is getting the breadcrumb array or list from the database (sql server 2005). My sql skills are not that great. Once I get the breadcrumb from the database what would be the best way to present it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing the users history in the database?  Wouldn't a breadcrumb be more of where the user has been?

In that case you'd probably want to store the page each time a user navigates to it, dropping off the first item when you have reached your maximum length.

the issue then becomes one of where to store that history and yeah a database may be an option.  You might also want to store that with the users session data if available.  there are stacks of ways to implement storage of history.

**EDIT**

This is added info to what mjv said.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could represent breadcrumb information in your markup.  There isn't a <breadcrumb> element in HTML so its debatable if any approach is semantically correct.  Look [here](http://www.simplebits.com/notebook/2004/02/04/sqxii.html) for a discussion of some of the approaches that people use.

I prefer using lists, then you could style it as shown in [this example](http://veerle.duoh.com/blog/comments/simple_scalable_css_based_breadcrumbs/).